# How to implement ASP.NET MVC Authentication Membership Provider using EXTJS?

Tags: asp.net, extjs

Does anyone know how to implement ASP.NET MVC authentication membership provider using EXTJS 4 MVC?

I would really appreciate the help.

Regards!

Answer (score 2):

It's actually quite easy.

1. You should have in your .NET code public Authenticate(username, password) method. Usually it gets generated automatically when you generate new project with Windows Services.
2. You need to make sure that your Windows Services are exposed via JSON endpoints. Here is what I used as a sample: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/deepm/archive/2010/05/14/silverlight-tv-episode-26-exposing-soap-json-and-odata-endpoints-from-ria-services.aspx
3. Then you make an Ajax calls to the Authenticate method usually using HTTP POST (I can post some code tomorrow from work - I think I had to customize it a bit)
4. After you authenticated server will return you back authentication cookie, which ExtJS automatically will send again to server along with each next request.

Let me know if you have additional questions.

Comment: Thanks Vlad, do you have any sample code to look at combining all these technologies?

Comment: I do. What exactly are you looking for?

Comment: I do have a lot of code, but I don't think I will be able to post my whole project anywhere. I can show some code snippets, but you gotta tell me what exactly are you looking for

Comment: thanks Vlad, well the authentication process... i want to do a login form that authenticates using membership and after that I can see a viewport with a sing out button. Appreciate your help

Comment: Vlad any resource that I can see to accomplish this? Thanks

Comment: Have you done anything at all? Do you have server part ready or no really?